# generate inputes automatically PUREj-s

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate inputs automatically according to user's input.

For example if he enter 2 then it will automatically generate:

> 2 x (select option(values : M-Mr) + text input + text input + date
>   input )

I already made the 3 last inputs(text-text-date) , I faced a probleme with the select option 
Thank you!!

```
<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: <br/>
                <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
            <div id="container"/>
```

and this is funtion :

```
function addFields(){
            var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
            var container = document.getElementById("container");
            while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            for (i=0;i<number;i++){
                container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i+1)));
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                var input1 = document.createElement("input");
                var input2 = document.createElement("input");

                input.type = "text";
                input1.type = "text";
                input2.type = "date";

                container.appendChild(input);
                container.appendChild(input1);
                container.appendChild(input2);
                container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

            }
        }
```

for the snipped code : 
https://jsfiddle.net/f4hptzsy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example adds the `select` element with two options included.
See comments in the code for explanation of how it works.

```js
// Identifies existing HTML elements
const member = document.getElementById("member");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// Calls `useNumber` when `member` changes
member.addEventListener("change", useNumber);


// Defines `useNumber`
// (The listener can automatically access the triggering event)
function useNumber(event){

  // The element where the event happened is the `target`
  const memberValue = event.target.value;

  //  Calls `addFields` if the value can be used as an integer
  const num = parseInt(memberValue);
  if(num){
    addFields(num);
  }
}

function addFields(number) {

  // Clears container
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }

  // Creates new elements and adds them to container
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i + 1)));

    // Defines a select element
    const dropdown = document.createElement("select");

    // Enumerates options and adds them to the select element
    let options = ["M", "Mr"];
    for (let option  of options){
      optionElement = document.createElement("option");
      optionElement.value = option;
      optionElement.innerHTML = option;
      dropdown.appendChild(optionElement);
    }

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    var input1 = document.createElement("input");
    var input2 = document.createElement("input");

    input.type = "text";
    input1.type = "text";
    input2.type = "date";

    // Adds the select element to the page
    container.appendChild(dropdown);

    // Adds other inputs to the page
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(input1);
    container.appendChild(input2);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="member" />
<br />
<div id="container"></div>
```

**EDIT**:
The `useNumber` function just tests if the input is a valid integer before calling `addFields`.
It would be fine to omit this function and have `addFields` itself be the event listener instead, like:

```js
// Identifies existing HTML elements
const member = document.getElementById("member");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// Calls `addFields` when `member` changes
member.addEventListener("change", addFields);

function addFields(event) { // We name the triggering event "event"

  // Gets value of element where the `change` event happened
  const memberValue = event.target.value;

  // Converts value to a number
  const number = parseInt(memberValue);

  // Makes sure conversion succeeded before proceding
  if(number){
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
      container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i + 1)));

      // Defines a select element
      const dropdown = document.createElement("select");

      // Enumerates options and adds them to the select element
      let options = ["M", "Mr"];
      for (let option  of options){
        optionElement = document.createElement("option");
        optionElement.value = option;
        optionElement.innerHTML = option;
        dropdown.appendChild(optionElement);
      }

      var input = document.createElement("input");
      var input1 = document.createElement("input");
      var input2 = document.createElement("input");

      input.type = "text";
      input1.type = "text";
      input2.type = "date";

      // Adds the select element to the page
      container.appendChild(dropdown);

      container.appendChild(input);
      container.appendChild(input1);
      container.appendChild(input2);
      container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="member" />
<br />
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: thank you sir for ur replay, can u please tell me what is the purpose of useNumber(event)

Comment: hey cat , sorry plz can i ask if it could be generated automatically from the input , i mean without clicking "Entre" after insert the value

Comment: Yes, you could listen for the `input` event instead of the `change` event like `member.addEventListener("input", addFields);`. Then any input the user applies to the "member" input (such as adding a character) would trigger the function, but the user might not expect this behavior. If you do this, you'd probably at least want to add code to clear the "member" input at the end of `addFields` (like `member.value = "";`).